# How to connect to a workgroup?

Tags: windows, workgroup

I have a server and a laptop in a workgroup. I am trying to add another laptop, and cannot find guidance online.

Is there a canonical guide, which you have followed and know to work?

---

[Update] I tried to ping the server from the second laptop, but could not

Comment: Joining a workgroup does not automatically [share folders](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-over-a-network-in-windows-b58704b2-f53a-4b82-7bc1-80f9994725bf) or [printers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/share-your-network-printer-c9a152b5-59f3-b6f3-c99f-f39e5bf664c3). What are you trying to achieve? https://www.digitalcitizen.life/workgroup-windows/

Comment: I want to access the server's file system from the second laptop, as I do from the first. The server already shares its drives. I set up the first laptop years ago and forgot to document how. On line guides seem to be incomplete. I seek a complete guide, for the laptop only, as the server is fine

Comment: On the first laptop (the one where it works), how do you access the files on the server? Do you click the drive in the File Explorer like in this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/ERPI8IB.png ? If so, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/map-a-network-drive-in-windows-29ce55d1-34e3-a7e2-4801-131475f9557d

Comment: Yes. Some time ago I mapped some network drives. I would do that on the second laptop- if it could see the server, but it cannot

Comment: Try setting a shortcut on the laptop, using the *full UNC path* to the shared folder. For example, if the server is MAWG-SVR, and the shared folder is at C:\shared, with share-name "shared", the path would be `\\MAWG-SVR\shared`.

Comment: SMB1 was deprecated and disabled some time ago due to security issues and it is that which was used for network name discovery. If you know the name of the server then you can usually type it in as suggested by @DrMoishePippik and it will "just work". Workgroups are not necessary to the process.

Comment: `\\server` is not working, nor is `\\server\data`  :-(   The server has a password, but IIRC, I was challenged the first time I accessed the server from the older laptop and not thereafter. No challenge with the new laptop

Comment: I tried to ping the server from the second laptop, but could not